# Is there any way to add redux reducer under the store admin.resource[RESOURCE].list level?

Tags: react-admin

I want to add some other information to my list request response, in react admin, there's totalReducer to get the total data from my list request response. I want to add another reducer in the same level in the store state tree, will that be possible?

```
admin.resources[RESOURCE_NAME].list {
    idsReducer,
    totalReducer,
    MyReducer
}
```